# AV-Receiver that supports HDMI resolution 5120x1440

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

I got the AV-receiver Onkyo TX-NR676E that supports 4K/60Hz.

I got an UltraWide 49" screen from Dell with max. resolution of 5120x1440.

It works fine with my MacBook connected directly to the display. But when I connect my computer with HDMI via the receiver the resolution goes down to 2560x1080 <- This is less than 4K, but it seems to be the max. resolution. I couldn't find any setting in the receiver to change this.

Now I'm maybe calculating wrong, cause I don't now how it really works, but 4K (3840*2160) seems in number of pixels more than (5120*1440), so the receiver should be able to transmit the signal, right?

Now the questions are:

**1. How could I make this work with this receiver?**

**2. Or what are the specs that I have to check on another receiver before buying, to be sure that this will work with the receiver?**

**3. Or does anybody know a certain receiver that works definitely with this resolution?**

Comment: Have you reviewed the receiver's manual?  Onkyo's Support site?

Comment: Yes, I also sent a message to the Onkyo support but didn't receive any answer.